# SwiftUI View method called but output missing

Tags: swift, swiftui, view

I have the View **AlphabetLetterDetail**:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AlphabetLetterDetail: View {
    var alphabetLetter: AlphabetLetter
    var letterAnimView : LetterAnimationView
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action:
                    animateLetter
            ) {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "alpha_be_1")!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 60.0, height: 120.0)
            }
            letterAnimView
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text(verbatim: alphabetLetter.name), displayMode: .inline)
    }
    
    func animateLetter(){
        print("tapped")
        letterAnimView.timerWrite()
    }
}
```

containing the View **letterAnimView** of Type **LetterAnimationView**:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LetterAnimationView: View {
    
    @State var Robot : String = ""
    let LETTER =
    ["alpha_be_1_81",
     "alpha_be_1_82",
     "alpha_be_1_83",
     "alpha_be_1_84",
     "alpha_be_1_85",
     "alpha_be_1_86",
     "alpha_be_1_87",
     "alpha_be_1_88",
     "alpha_be_1_89",
     "alpha_be_1_90",
     "alpha_be_1"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.center){
            Image(Robot)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 80, height: 160, alignment: .center)
                .onAppear(perform: timerWrite)
        }
    }
    
    func timerWrite(){
        var index = 0
        let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.08, repeats: true) {(Timer) in
            Robot = LETTER[index]
            print("one frame")
            index += 1
            if (index > LETTER.count - 1){
                Timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me a fine animation, as coded in **func timerWrite()** and performed by **.onAppear(perform: timerWrite)**.
After commenting **//.onAppear(perform: timerWrite)** I try animating by clicking

```
Button(action: animateLetter)
```

but nothing happens.
Maybe I got two different instances of **letterAnimView**, if so why?
Can anybody of you competent guys intentify my mistake?

Regards - Klaus

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to store `View`s, they are `struct`s so they are copied. Instead, create an `ObservableObject` to encapsulate this functionality.

I created `RobotModel` here with other minor changes:

```
class RobotModel: ObservableObject {
    private static let atlas = [
        "alpha_be_1_81",
        "alpha_be_1_82",
        "alpha_be_1_83",
        "alpha_be_1_84",
        "alpha_be_1_85",
        "alpha_be_1_86",
        "alpha_be_1_87",
        "alpha_be_1_88",
        "alpha_be_1_89",
        "alpha_be_1_90",
        "alpha_be_1"
    ]

    @Published private(set) var imageName: String

    init() {
        imageName = Self.atlas.last!
    }

    func timerWrite() {
        var index = 0
        let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.08, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.imageName = Self.atlas[index]
            print("one frame")
            index += 1
            if index > Self.atlas.count - 1 {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct AlphabetLetterDetail: View {
    @StateObject private var robot = RobotModel()
    let alphabetLetter: AlphabetLetter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: animateLetter) {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "alpha_be_1")!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 60.0, height: 120.0)
            }
            LetterAnimationView(robot: robot)
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text(verbatim: alphabetLetter.name), displayMode: .inline)
    }

    func animateLetter() {
        print("tapped")
        robot.timerWrite()
    }
}
```

```
struct LetterAnimationView: View {
    @ObservedObject var robot: RobotModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.center){
            Image(robot.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 80, height: 160, alignment: .center)
                .onAppear(perform: robot.timerWrite)
        }
    }
}
```